# How do I pick the number that I want from the particular column

Tags: python

I got a question regarding this python question. Whenever I get a user to input some numbers. Eg -> 123456789, and I want to pick the 2nd column position of the number that the user just inserted. The first thing tried is just print(num(2)), but it doesn't work. Is that anyway I can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```py
num=123456789
print(str(num)[2])
```

btw, python index start at 0